# EF Core migrations - remove historic migrations

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I think the title is a tiny bit misleading, so let me explain what I want to do.

I have a series of EF Core migrations (about 40) and some of them are bad. This was caused by a merge when we tried to merge two different branches each with a new migration into the trunk (or master or main or whatever we're supposed to call it now) and messed up the DB snapshot real bad.

Anyway, long story short: is there a way to delete all previous migrations and pretend like we're starting from scratch, scaffolding the code-first DBContext from the current state of the DB and then create a "first" migration for new changes?

I'm assuming I'd have to delete the migrations in the data access project, plus remove the _EFMigrationsHistory table or at least truncate it.

Is there anything else I'd need to do?

Comment: Let's just get the obvious questions out of the way: no, I can't roll back. Not the merges, not the migrations. I either have to live with it or start fresh.

Comment: Other schema management systems, such as Flyway, support rolling up all of the previous migration history into "baselines" or snapshots of the current schema which then allows you then to remove all of the prior migration history. Does EF not support such a thing?

Comment: No, EF doesn't directly support such a thing. You more or less have to "trick" it into thinking you're scaffolding a new code-first migration from an existing DB and delete all the old migrations.

Answer (score -1):

If i understand correctly and we are talking about code first approach,

then you can just use "remove-migrations" command in the package manager console

and change database name in the connectionString in order to create a new

database.

Comment: Does `remove-migrations` remove tables and database as well?

Comment: I can't just "create a new database" in production.

Comment: @ChanGuanYu  It removes the migrations and if you change the the name of the database in the connectionstring you can create new one with (add-migration) and (update-database).

Comment: @CaptainKenpachi Ofcourse you can read my previous comment

Comment: What happens to all the data created by the application? We have millions of transactions captured.